# Documentation for changes to pst-eucl package

Tags: pstricks, texlive, pst-eucl

I just noticed today that when I use the `eucl` package, I get the following message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.tex
`PST-Euclide v1.47, 2013/03/12  (Dominique RODRIGUEZ)
 This version uses the pst-xkey package for managing parameters
 Please read the doc, some macros have a new syntax
 use option old for upward compatibility)
File: pst-eucl.tex 2013/03/12  v1.47 `PST-eucl' (dr)
)
```

I'm currently using TeXLive 2013 (I think I updated just two weeks ago).  The most recent documentation I have for the `eucl` package is dated `January 9th, 2013`.  In appendix B of this documentation it is mentioned that changes have been made, but when I compare this documentation with the one I have from TeXLive 2011, I can't find any differences.

Does anyone know where I can go to readily find out what these changes are?

**UPDATE**

When I run `diff` on `euclide-english-tex` versions for 2013 and 2011, I only get very superficial changes:  mostly spelling from French to English.  Also, when I look at Changes, I don't find anything which mentions what these *syntactic* changes are.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `pst-xkey` since 2005 and the message refers to a version before that date.

Comment: If this is the case, where can one find the older version interface documentation *vs* the new one? That's what the OP is after in my opinion.